# Why can’t I see a forward arrow in Firefox 56’s address bar?

Tags: firefox, firefox-profile

This is a screencap from my Firefox 56:

[image: Screencap from Firefox 56]

The browser itself works, except for one issue: The forward arrow doesn't seem to appear, unless this is a new behavior to Firefox 56 I'm not aware of?

I'm on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.2, Mac mini 2011 if this is relevant.

Is there a solution to this, or am I pointlessly worrying over a built-in feature?

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there a solution to this, or am I pointlessly worrying over a built-in feature?*

There isn't anything wrong with your browser application. This is simply the standard behavior within Firefox 56:

[image: Firefox 56]

In the example screenshot that you posted, you will find that if you clicked on the hyperlink that says **New BMW X4**, waited for the page to load, and *then* clicked the back-arrow button, your forward-arrow button will appear.  Essentially, it doesn't appear unless there actually is a page within your browser session history where you could potentially navigate forward.

---

In contrast, newer versions of Firefox will show the forward-arrow button by default, but it will be dimmed unless there is a page available in your current browser session where you can navigate forward:

[image: Firefox 61]

---

Screenshot sources:
[What’s new in Firefox 56](https://winaero.com/blog/whats-new-firefox-56/)
[Firefox 61 Released, Here’s Everything You Need to Know](https://winaero.com/blog/firefox-61-released/)